# Share members between two sites - MSM?

Tags: members, multi-site-manager

We have an upcoming project coming up which will have two sides, let's call one the marketing site, and the other is an app.

The basic idea is the marketing site will sell access to the app, so the user will sign up through the marketing site to have access to the app.

So basically we need to be able to share members and only the members between both sites. Is MSM suitable for this?

Technically, it could be done through a single site but I don't want to be mixing up the channels and other data between the marketing site and the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly share members between different sites when using Multisite Manager.

You mention that this could be done with a single site and, to be honest, that's precisely how I would approach it (unless the sites needed to be served under different domains). I don't understand what you mean when you say "mixing channels and other data" and why this would present a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I meant I didn't want the channels for the marketing site mixed in with the channels for the app. I would prefer to keep them both separate (apart from the members) to keep it simple and logical.

Comment: Keeping things "simple and logical" to me means using one site instead of two. It's the nature of the beast, but MSM can get extremely complicated. Still though, either way can work.